# scrolling a div diagonally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make a div scroll diagonally? A regular scroll would go up/down or left/right, but I'd like to make the div scroll up *and* to the right **or** down *and* to the left.

[See visual representation](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/06qfwen6/Unbenannt1.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  The image just shows to rectangles askew, not tited...

Comment: I know many people don't like W3 Schools, but take a look at this to see if it answers your question http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: dont know who was so kind and corrected me that but, yeah i was a lil bit wrong with my explanation! have another look to the top :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say scrolling? Do you mean a jQuery animation?

Comment: no i mean scrolling with the scrollbar or mousewheel. not jquery events...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: as required by the OP, I've updated the example code to introduce a correction factor, required to change the diagonal movement direction and degree.

If you want to use jQuery you'll have to download the [MouseWheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) plugin.

Then, you can write a simple function binded to the `mousewheel` event, such as:

**HTML**

```
<div id="block"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#block {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Alternative 1: JS using CSS top and left**

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('mousewheel', function(evt,delta){
        var $block = $('#block'),
            // retrieves the top and left coordinates
            top = parseInt($block.css('top')),
            left = parseInt($block.css('left')),
            // mouse wheel delta is inverted respect to the direction, so we need to
            // normalize it against the direction
            offset = -1 * delta,
            // X and Y factors allows to change the diagonal movement direction and
            // degree. Negative values inverts the direction.
            factorX = 5,
            factorY = 2,
            // calculates the new position. NOTE: if integers only are used for factors,
            // then `Math.floor()` isn't required.
            newTop = top + Math.floor(offset * factorY),
            newLeft = left - Math.floor(offset * factorX);

        // moves the block
        $block.css({ 
            top: newTop + 'px',
            left: newLeft + 'px'
        });
    });
});
```

**Alternative 2: JS using offset()**

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('mousewheel', function(evt,delta){
        var $block = $('#block'),
            // retrieves the top and left coordinates
            position = $block.offset(),
            // mouse wheel delta is inverted respect to the direction, so we need to
            // normalize it against the direction
            offset = -1 * delta,
            // X and Y factors allows to change the diagonal movement direction and
            // degree. Negative values inverts the direction.
            factorX = 5,
            factorY = 2,
            // calculates the new position. NOTE: if integers only are used for factors,
            // then `Math.floor()` isn't required.
            newTop = position.top + Math.floor(offset * factorY),
            newLeft = position.left - Math.floor(offset * factorX);

        // moves the block
        $block.offset({ top: newTop, left: newLeft });
    });
});
```

Now you can move the box up&right by scrolling up and vice-versa by scrolling down.
In this example, on every `mousewheel` event, the callback function:

1. retrieves the current element position (`top` and `left` CSS properties)
2. inverts the delta value returned by the `mousewheel` event, so that scrolling up we have a negative delta, and scrolling down we have a positive delta
3. set the factor values required to define diagonal movement direction and degree
4. calculates the new position
5. moves the object.

To change degree and direction, just change `factorX` and/or `factorY` values, so that:

- negative values inverts the direction, and
- different values change the degree (for example, X = 2 and Y = 5 makes the element moving with a much more closed angle, respect to X = 5 and Y = 2).

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/Ntxud/) you can test.

**Alternative 3: JS using cos() and sin()**

```
$(function(){
    $(window).on('mousewheel', function(evt,delta){
        var $block = $('#block'),
            // read current block position
            position = $block.offset(),
            // inverts the delta; scroll up == -1 - scroll down == +1
            direction = -1 * delta,
            // sets the angle and converts it in radians
            angle = 45 * Math.PI / 180,
            // set displacememt factor
            factorX = Math.cos(angle) * direction,
            factorY = Math.sin(angle) * direction,
            // calculate the new position
            newTop = position.top + factorY,
            newLeft = position.left - factorX;

        // moves the block
        $block.offset({ top: newTop, left: newLeft });
    });
});
```

In this example, what to change is the value in `angle` (45 in this example). Everything else works just like the others examples.

Last thing, if it's required to change the *velocity* of the movement, just multiply `factorX` and/or `factorY` by the wanted coefficient (for example, 1.5 for one and half time of the velocity, or 2 for twice the velocity, etc.).

It's possibile to try it in a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/4ptTx/).

---

**EDIT**

Just for the sake of knowledge, you can reach the same goal using [CSS Transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform). This allows you to take advantage from GPU accelerated hardware. (Further informations can be found in the article of [Smashing Magazine](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/) and [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)).

**HTML**

```
<div id="block"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#block {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var blockOffsetX = 50,
        blockOffsetY = 200;

    $('#block').css({
        transform: 'translate3d(' + blockOffsetX + 'px' + ', ' + blockOffsetY + 'px, 0)'
    });

    $(window).on('mousewheel', function(evt,delta){
        var $block = $('#block'),
            offset = -1 * delta;
            factorX = 5,
            factorY = 2;

        blockOffsetX -= offset * factorX;
        blockOffsetY += offset * factorY;
        $block.css({ 
            transform: 'translate3d(' + blockOffsetX + 'px, ' + blockOffsetY + 'px, 0)'
        });
    });
});
```

However, as you can see in this example, you'll need to keep track of the element X,Y position, because it's a little bit complicated to retrieve these values directly from the CSS. Moreover, this example is kept easier, but in production you'll have to support every vendor specific CSS property (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-ms-`, etc.).

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/JBDSG/) (if it doesn't work, you probably will have to edit the code according to the specific prefixed CSS property for your browser).

---

**EDIT**: Since the OP has seen that listening to the `scroll` event it was the better choice for him, I've added the relative code (*only the JS code is reported here, since HTML and CSS are pretty the same as the first example*):

```
$(function(){
    var lastScrollYPos = 0;
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $block = $('#block'),
            // retrieves the top and left coordinates
            position = $block.offset(),
            // X and Y factors allows to change the diagonal movement direction and
            // degree. Negative values inverts the direction.
            factorX = 1,
            factorY = 1,
            // retrieves current vertical scrolling position and calculate the
            // relative offset
            scrollYPos = $this.scrollTop(),
            offset = Math.abs(scrollYPos - lastScrollYPos),
            // mouse wheel delta is inverted respect to the direction, so we need to
            // normalize it against the direction
            direction = scrollYPos > lastScrollYPos ? -1 : 1,
            // calculates the new position. NOTE: if integers only are used for factors,
            // then `Math.floor()` isn't required.
            newTop = position.top + Math.floor(direction * offset * factorY),
            newLeft = position.left - Math.floor(direction * offset * factorX);

        // moves the block
        $block.offset({ top: newTop, left: newLeft });
        lastScrollYPos = scrollYPos;
    });
});
```

Here's a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/JjxPM/).

---

**BONUS: IDEA**

Instead of use common local variables for every element, HTML5 `data-*` properties could be used to store element's data (for example: correction factor, last position, etc.), then jQuery `.data()` method could be used to retrieve these data and process them.

PRO:

- Decouple the callback function from the element
- Customize every element on the page to act differently from each other

CONS:

- It will probably affect the rendering performance in some way, especially whether many elements have to be managed at same time by the callback function.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. i will test it, as soon im from the work! i appreciate this very much, i will let you know how it worked for me!

Comment: it seems to me that the diagonal line is always the same? how can i reduce the degree how the block is scrolled to. you know what i mean? thanks

Comment: diagonal line is the same because mousewheel event returns always +1 or -1 delta. Changing the diagonal angle requires you introduce a factor value in top (or Y) and/or left (or X) properties, that increase or decrement the amount of the offset value.

Comment: would you show me with that example which value i have to change. i dont really get it! maybe you could comment it into the fiddle! that would be awesome...

Comment: I've updated the fiddle relative to the first example, adding some comments to make it clearer. Hope it can help you. ASAP, I'll update the examples here too.

Comment: first i would like to thank you for your effort. i recognized that in your first example (the updated fiddle) the block slightly moves to the top with every up or down scroll you do!
in the css example it works pretty good... but i still dont get it which value ive to change when you want to have a different degree... i will following testing!

Comment: glad to be helpful. I've updated examples and demos, adding comments and extending a little bit my explanation. hope this can help you.

Comment: sorry but i need some of your help again. this works like a charm... but i realised i need it for the scrollbars for those who dont have a mousewheel or trackpad too. is there any possibility? or maybe you could give me an approach! thanks

Comment: sorry for late reply, I'm absorbed by the work a bit. Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/JjxPM/) that works with vertical scroll but, honestly, it seems to me useless since by scrolling the page, the element will move and at the same time scrolls with the page. IMHO, it's better to support mouse/trackpad and touch events only for this kind of animations, ignoring scrollbars. Happy coding!

Comment: late replay? i guess 2 hours are more than comfortable haha. thanks for that, actually i cant test it yet... but i will do tomorrow and give you a reply! thank you!

Comment: okay i couldnt wait so i tested. it works, but with every scroll up and down the div moves slightly to the left or right while moving up and down like before! why it does?
let me tell you why i need it: i have a scrolling page with lots of div layer. these have background pictures with a diagonally white gap in it... the text should fit in scroll up between this gap. thats why i need a diagonal scroll of divs. i cant assume that everyone has a touchpad or mousewheel. some may have not

Comment: I see. Ok. Updated the demo. Now the box follows the right direction. The code works like the others, the difference is that here the event triggered is `scroll` and direction and offset are calculated from the vertical scroll page position.

Comment: okay now im glad! everything is working, just have to write it to a function that i can call in on different divs! again a big thank you for you!

Comment: another little question, is it possible to do this with position() instead of offset? offset defines it all over the whole document, and my page has a very long scrollbar. that means every element inside the div is scrolled far away...

Comment: Yes. Just decide what is the container to attach the event listener  and change DIV `position` to `relative` if it's inside a container different by the main document.

Comment: btw thanks again for your effort! i dont think its a matter of course!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the onScroll event, detect if the user is scrolling vertically or horizontally and then appropriately scroll the other direction.

Example:

**JS**

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$("#diagonalscroller").scroll(function(e) {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();    
    if (scrollTop === lastScrollTop) {
        // Vertical scroll position is unchanged, so we're scrolling horizontal.
        $(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollLeft());
    } else {
        // Vertical scroll position has changed, so we're scrolling vertical.
        $(this).scrollLeft($(this).scrollTop());
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Try scrolling using the scrollbars</h1>
<div id="diagonalscroller">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/800/" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#diagonalscroller {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

Watch the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mXwbT/).

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. i will test it, as soon im from the work! i appreciate this very much, i will let you know how it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Old question.. but who ever comes across this question might like

> > [this pen](http://codepen.io/pixelass/pen/ozbtL)

It's a concept for a diagonal webpage layout.

The code is to big to post here and it is probably more than the OP asked.

Gotta post code so. here's the part that does the magic. (using Modernizr for cross browser support)

```
  var $window = $(window);
  var con = $('#content');
  $window.on('touchmove scroll', function() {
    var winScroll = $window.scrollTop() * -1;
    if (!Modernizr.csstransforms3d && Modernizr.csstransforms) {
      con.css({
        transform: 'translate(' + winScroll + 'px,' + winScroll + 'px)'
      });
    } else if (Modernizr.csstransforms3d) {
      con.css({
        transform: 'translate3d(' + winScroll + 'px,' + winScroll + 'px,0)'
      });
    } else {
      con.css({
        left: winScroll,
        top: winScroll
      });
    }
  });
```